# Angular JS ngModel: Transform data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So we have a model with a 'time' in it, formatted like '14:00:00'. We are using angular-boostrap's timepicker, but it expects a JS date object or an ISO datetime string.

My first thought was to do a directive that would add $parser/$formatter to ngModel controller that would convert it on the way in and way out to the format we need. This works smashingly for output, but not for input.

I've made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1820/

```
myApp.directive('timespan',function($filter){
    var dateFilter = $filter('date');
    function parser(data){
        return dateFilter(data,'HH:mm:ss');
    };

    function formatter(data){
        var converted = '2000-01-01T' + data + '-06:00';
        return converted;
    };

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(parser);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(formatter);
        }
    };
});
```

As you cans when you open the fiddle the 12:00:00 isn't reflected by the timepicker. If you look at the console its complaining that ngModel is in the wrong format. If you change the time with the picker you'll see that $scope.myModel.time is in the correct format.

How do I get the ngModel to the correct format before it gets to timepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timepicker in angular-bootstrap expects the `$modelValue` to be a date (it passes it to the `Date()` constructor and then parses hours and minutes from the object).  Since it writes its own [$render()](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/timepicker/timepicker.js#L175) function, based on `$modelValue`, your formatters aren't being used.

I'm afraid you're not going to get what you want without doing some surgery on the angular-bootstrap code.  It would likely be easier to write a controller with two input fields (for hours and minutes).

Comment: formatter chain isn't in render, formatter chain is in the $watch (ngModelWatch) and is run on every digest.

You are however right that timepickers use of modelValue instead of viewValue is what was causing the issue. Since we are using 0.8.0 we just moded angular-bootstrap to use the viewValue and it works as expected now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create directive for your Model Value input. This directive would 
receive date in the same format as timepicker - timestamp or Date object and display it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think timepicker must use $viewValue in render method. Therefore the best solution is this surgery on the angular-bootstrap code.

Change $modelValue to $viewValue in [render function](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/timepicker/timepicker.js#L175).